# Is it possible to use Bitcoins from an old or changed adress confirmed on the blockchain?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, unconfirmed-transactions, lost-bitcoins, lost-transactions

I sent & Confirmed bitcoins from my Luno Wallet using the adress from a binary miner. Next day the Binary miner said they received the Bitcoins BUT are UNABLE to use them to facilitate payment due to me because of
1). Delay of network 
2). the the adress was old & it changed so the bitcoins are no longer active/cannot be used.

Answer (score 3):

You are likely being scammed.

An address remains valid and usable forever as long as its private key is accessible. If any service is generating and deleting private keys, it is run by completely incompetent people and should not be used.

The "Delay of network" argument is equally baseless - if they have received the coins, they are in sync with the network, and can spend those coins trivially.

Do not send these people any more money. Essentially all mining services short of buying and operating your own mining hardware are scams.